# Pie slice changes color on drilldown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

When I click the blue slice, it'll bring me to a drilldown of 3 slices. When I return from it, the color of a single slice has changed. It doesn't matter what color I change it to it always changes and it's always the same one.

[image: Start], [image: Drilldown], [image: Return]

This is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ng1kvmxh/21/) of my code but the problem doesn't occur here. These are my colors:

`colors: ['#FF0000', '#7F7F7F', '#C00000', '#FFC000', '#4F81BD', '#00B050', '#92D050']` 
Happens across browsers

Comment: though its not reproducing on fiddle ,one thing you can do is : you may define colors while creating pie.So while filling data to your pie define fix color with each slice, Same like what you are doing in your drilldowns -ground

Comment: Please post live example where the problem occurs. Maybe you are executing some other code that is causing change of color?

Comment: @KacperMadej I don't have the ability to do that. Everything is recreated in the fiddle that would affect the colors

Comment: What is different in the fiddle and in the page with the error? You can remove or add code (JS, CSS, HMTL) from one to another until you find the source of the problem or recreate the issue in a live example, like jsFiddle.